# LEFT AND RIGHT function lambda expression c#

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

How can I from using
LEFT AND RIGHT function lambda expression in c#?
for example:

```
"SELECT [Code]   FROM [City]  WHERE LEFT ([Code] ,3)=" + Digit + " LEFT AND RIGHT function in ([Code],6)<>111111 order by Code"
```

Can you help me to convert the above code to lambda expression in c#

Comment: Would a String.StartsWith or .EndsWith help?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of the code above

Comment: The code is a number

Answer (score 0):

Base on your example, assuming you tried to format string with lambda. Please let me know if I misunderstand what you try to achieve.

```
Func<int, string> myFunc = d => $"SELECT [Code]   FROM [City]  WHERE LEFT ([Code] ,3)={d} LEFT AND RIGHT function in ([Code],6)<>111111 order by Code";
```

Comment: _db.City.Select(c=> (DbFunctions.Left(c.Id.ToString(),2)== StartDigit.ToString()) && (DbFunctions.Right(c.Id.ToString(),5)<>"00000")).Tolist();

Comment: Hi @tablighjonoub. Mind to tell me what problem do you have? And also please provide more information about the problem. Like the answer result is not produce as expected.

Comment: The piece of your code seems like selecting a list of bool. I can not understand about what data type of `_db` and `_db.City` is. I assume `_db.City` is `List` or `IEnumerable`.

Comment: A little bit clear for me now. Seems like the code under `_db.City.Select` is the requirement. In `GetAllCityCustom`, it should be return `List<bool>` instead of `List<City>`. Try `_db.City.Where` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CityCustomRepository:GenericCrudRepository<City>
    {
        private ShopEntities _db;
        public CityCustomRepository(ShopEntities db) : base(db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }

        public List<City> GetAllCityCustom(int StartDigit)
        {
            return _db.City.Where(c=> DbFunctions.Left(c.Id.ToString(), 2) == StartDigit.ToString() && DbFunctions.Right(c.Id.ToString(), 5) <> "00000").ToList();
           
        }
    }
```

1. To select the first city, I select the province

2- Province code 30

3- The province code is taken

4- The city code is 7 digits

2 digits of city code are separated from the left and compared with 2 digits of provincial code

And after that, the 5 digits to the right of the city code will be separated, this time it must be opposite to 00,000

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer

```
public List<City> GetAllCity(object StartDigit)
        {
            try
            {
                return _db.City.Where(c => c.Id.ToString().StartsWith(StartDigit.ToString()) && !c.Id.ToString().EndsWith("00000")).ToList();
            }
            catch
            {
                return null;
            }
            
        }
```

Just consider the type of data type as an object

> GetAllCityCustom(int StartDigit)

And use the following command

> c => c.Id.ToString().StartsWith(StartDigit.ToString()) &&
> !c.Id.ToString().EndsWith("00000")

Thanks for the tips dear friends